# Problem using enumerate with align

Tags: align, enumerate

I'm having a little bit of trouble with using enumerate and align.

I'm trying to get this: 
[image]

But it is not working for me.

Comment: is it necessary to use `\ref` later to refer to any of these items?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misusing the `align` and `align*` environments. Your material is more properly displayed using a basic `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}         % for '\text' macro
\usepackage{array}           % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} % math-mode 'l' column type
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{lLl}
1. & x + y = y + x & Comutatividade da soma \\
2. & (x + y) + z = x + (y + z) & Associatividade da soma\\
3. & \exists e\in A\text{ tal que $x + e = x$ para todo $x$} & Elemento neutro da soma\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
  1. \, & x + y = y + x && \text{Comutatividade da soma} \\
  2. \, & (x + y) + z = x + (y + z) && \text{Associatividade da soma}\\
  3. \, & \exists e \in A \text{ tal que } x + e = x \text{ para todo } x && \text{Elemento neutro da soma}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would add `\hspace{\labelsep}` rather than `\,` to  emulate the skip of a real list.